# Force XCode file to stay in place

Tags: xcode

I'm in XCode 7 (though this has been an issue since prob XCode 4) with 2 files open, one on the left, one on the right.
I'm not using the assistant editor.  Rather simply opened them each in their own tab?? within the single xcode shell, side-by-side.

The feature I find insanely annoying is this scenario... I have fileA open on the left pane, and fileB open on the right pane.  I run the project, and if there's a debug breakpoint set, or some other issue that causes XCode to pause, it automatically replaces fileA on the left pane, with whatever file is causing an issue.

I don't want fileA replaced.  I put the windows in the arrangement I wanted them.  Is there an XCode option that won't do this automatic replacement of fileA.

Comment: Turn off breakpoint?

Comment: I want and need the breakpoint.  When I'm debugging, I have the windows I want to see opened and arranged like I want them.  When a breakpoint is hit, XCode will not choose to open the breakpointed file in a new window, or if already open, scroll it to the position.  Instead, and infuriatingly, it replaces whatever window I have open in whatever it considers the "main" window, and replaces that file with the file where the breakpoint was hit.  If you ask me that's a really stupid behavior, and can't imagine why that was the approach taken by the XCode group